# How can I load different log4j2 config files depending on environment (dev, test, production) based on jboss system property using CDI

Tags: java, cdi

I have a requirement to load different log4j2 config files (log4j2-dev.xml, log4j-test.xml) using CDI
I Spring this can be achieved using

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:conf/log4j-${ENV-NAME}.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Is there a way to achieve the same using cdi-weld?

Comment: Take a look at deltaspike